# Cannot compile Cairo C code on Windows 10

Tags: c, compilation, windows-10, gtk3, cairo

I am trying to compile the zetcode [lines](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/) on Windows 10 using [msys64](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php).

I use the following compilation command:

```
gcc example.c -o example `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo gtk+-3.0`
```

and get the following error:

```
-bash: pkg-config: command not found
example.c:1:19: fatal error: cairo.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cairo.h>
```

However I did **pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-cairo** before and the installation was successful. When I type **pacman -Ss mingw-w64-i686-cairo
** I get the following:

```
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-cairo 1.15.2-4 [installed]
    Cairo vector graphics library (mingw-w64)
```

When I run **gcc -v** I get:

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-msys
Configured with: /msys_scripts/gcc/src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-msys --prefix=/usrable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --diso --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libg --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-isl-version-cith-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)

Last but not least, If I follow the instruction on this [website](http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/44) I can compile the **lines** code. However, GTK3 version provided is very old and cannot run newer [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723638/how-do-i-change-the-mouse-cursor-over-a-gtkdrawingarea-in-gtk3).

The paths to Cairo.h are:

C:\MinGW\include\cairo for the outdated (but working) GTK+3 install

and

C:\msys64\mingw32\include\cairo

and

C:\msys64\mingw64\include\cairo for the newer (but not working) GTK3 install using msys64

Which directory is MSYS64 trying to find the Cairo library?

Comment: Have you made sure the paths where the compiler looks for includes are correct?

Comment: The folder C:\msys64\mingw64\include\cairo does exist. How do I check where the compiler looks for includes?

Comment: `gcc -v`, I believe. And `gcc -I dir/ect/ory` to add a directory to search for includes.

Comment: Cannot make sense of the **gcc -v** output! Do you have a better idea?

Comment: How are you compiling? What are your arguments to the compiler? The standard way to compile a single C file that uses cairo is `gcc foo.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo)`. No idea if calling pkg-config inline like this works on Windows 10 with msys64. The idea is: Add the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo` to the compiler arguments.

Comment: If I run **gcc example.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo)** I still get the same ** fatal error: cairo.h: No such file or directory** error

Answer (score 0):

You showed two messages.  Lines two and three came from the compiler.  The first line came from the shell.  That first bug caused the second bug.  It says that the `pkg-config` command doesn't exist.  You need to install its package.  Use this command (it installs other useful packages, too):

```
pacboy sync base-devel
```

(You don't need to name `cairo` in the `pkg-config` command; `gtk+-3.0` names the packages that it needs.)