# How to handle mouse motion events in GTK3?

Tags: c, mouseevent, gtk3, cairo

I am trying to implement the following feature using C/GTK3/Cairo:

-Left click on an **GtkDrawingArea** Widget and printf the coordinates Xo and Yo.

-While keeping the left button down, move the mouse and draw a line conecting (Xo,Yo) to the current mouse position.

-Release the left mouse button and printf("something")

How do I do this? Anyone knows of a good tutorial showing how to handle mouse clicl-move events?

So far, the best I found was this zetcode [lines](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/) (which shows how to handle mouse click events but not button-down/move/button-up and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712704/how-do-i-set-the-mouse-cursor-to-cross-hair-over-a-gtkdrawingarea) , which explains how to change the mouse cursor when hovering over a Widget.

Thanks

Comment: With the first link you should be able to implement your steps 1 and 3. If that is not sufficient, please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem.

Comment: For step 2 you need to save where you pressed the button and then handle `"motion-notify-event"` for any movement of the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you see [this GtkDrawingArea demo](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/demos/gtk-demo/drawingarea.c) from the Gtk people? This one is written in C, but [there is a Python version](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/-/blob/master/examples/demo/demos/drawingarea.py) of the same program (links updated - thanks [@kyuuhachi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5183809/)).

Anyway, in the constructor (`__init__`), calls are connected to the `motion_notify_event`.

You also need to connect to the `button_press_event` and the `button_release_event`.

Then, on button press, you save the coordinates of the start point. (and save it to the end point too, which are the same for now).

On each motion_notify_event, you delete the previous line (by overwriting), and redraw it to the new end point.

Finally, when the button is released, the line is final.

It's *much* easier if you use a canvas widget, for example [GooCanvas,](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GooCanvas?action=show&redirect=GooCanvas) which takes care of most of the updating. You can just update the coordinates of the line object, and it will move itself. Also you can easily remove lines. The 'algorithm' is similar as above:

- Connect `button_press_event`, `button_release_event`, and `motion_notifyevent` to the canvas,
- When a button press occurs, create a `GooCanvas.polyline` object, and set begin and endpoint,
- Update the endpoint on each `motion_notify_event`
- Finalize with a `button_release_event`.

Comment: Both links are dead. Please fix.

Comment: I think the correct links are [C](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/demos/gtk-demo/drawingarea.c) and [Python](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/-/blob/master/examples/demo/demos/drawingarea.py). Says the edit queue is full if I try to edit, so I'll just put a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Kyuuhachi! I'll update the addresses above.